# How can I deserialize a single field from an array of objects with serde_json?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have JSON where a key has an array of objects and I'm only interested in one of the strings within that:

```
{
    "actors": [{
        "name": "Bob",
        "foo": "bar"
    }, {
        "name": "Jim",
        "foo": "baz"
    }],
    "fruits": [{
        "name": "Pineapple",
        "foo": "bar"
    }, {
        "name": "Apple",
        "foo": "baz"
    }]
}
```

I have

```rust
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.110

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Name {
    pub name: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
    pub actors: Vec<Name>,
    pub fruits: Vec<Name>,
}
```

How can I flatten that so I can have `Vec<String>` rather than `Vec<Name>`? e.g. I want to end up with

```
actors: ["Bob", "Jim"],
fruits: ["Pineapple", "Apple"],
```

Comment: You want to replace `Vec<Name>` with `Vec<String>` but still able to use the same format (e.g. `"actors" : [{"name": "Bob", ...}]`) rather than flattanned (e.g. `"actors" : ["Bob", ..]`)?

Comment: I just want it flattened i.e. `"actors": ["Bob", "Jim",...]`

Comment: May you also clarify that in your answer?

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the OP. What you answered seems to be the wrong way round.

Comment: Ok, then it still not clear what do you mean by "end up with" section. You want to transform json? Or just print the data in the specified format?

Comment: I want `Data`'s `Vec<Name>` fields to be `Vec<String>` that's just the name of the inner json object.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=607f6e1f17d6c520540b884202d0b9ad)